# Unable to instantiate a viewController from Storyboard as rootViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Being new in swift, i am trying to use storyboard to go to LoginController using following code

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{

    var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
    var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications();

    var navCtrl =  UINavigationController();
    var isLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(USERDEFAULT_ISLOGGEDIN);
    if(isLoggedIn)
    {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var mainController: CategoriesController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SEGUE_CATEGORIES) as CategoriesController
        navCtrl.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true);
    }
    else
    {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var mainController: LoginController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOGIN) as LoginController
        navCtrl.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true);
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = navCtrl;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();

    return true
}
```

However it just shows blank screen. What is wrong in assigning navController as rootViewController?

Comment: `self.window` is nil? Replace `self.window?` with `self.window!` in the two calls. It's probably an error if window is nil, so you should force unwrap.

Comment: it gives bad exc error then @MatthiasBauch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not created a window, so `self.window` will be nil. The system creates the window only if you start the app from a xib or from a storyboard. If you don't use these you have to create it yourself.

Since you conditionally unwrap by using `?` the assignment of navCtrl and the call to makeKeyAndVisible() won't be exectuted at all.

Simply create a UIWindow before using it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    // ...
    self.window!.rootViewController = navCtrl;
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible();
    return true
}
```

I would recommend to unwrap all calls that involve `window` with `!`. Not having a window should be an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I think you cannot push UINavigationController until you set its root ViewController.

```
var navCtrl
let isLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(USERDEFAULT_ISLOGGEDIN);
if (isLoggedIn)
{
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var mainController: CategoriesController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SEGUE_CATEGORIES) as CategoriesController

    navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController:mainController)
}
else
{
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var mainController: LoginController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOGIN) as LoginController
    navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController:mainController)
}
```